# Centos 6 VPS OpenVPN server failing

Tags: centos, openvpn, sysvinit

I like to run several services from my Centos server and Debian computer from home. Since I had my own domain for my email, I was interested in using my domain name with a VPS static IP to act as a pseudo static IP for my home server through VPN.

So I got a CentOS6.3 VPS from vps.net and started setting up an OpenVPN server using this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-6). Once I finished with the configuration, `service openvpn start` always returned with -

`Starting openvpn:                                 [FAILED]`

So I removed and purged all of the packages and restarted. Then I kept looking at and trying other tutorials ranging from RHEL to ubuntu. I have rebooted purged and updated repositories but still can't find out what I am doing wrong. So I appreciate anyones help at finding my error.

```
$(uname -r)
-bash: 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64

openvpn --versionOpenVPN 2.3.14 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  7 2016
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, LZO 2.03
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2016 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=yes enable_fragment=yes enable_http_proxy=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_lzo_stub=no enable_management=yes enable_multi=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_password_save=yes enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_pthread=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_small=no enable_socks=yes enable_ssl=yes enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_iproute_path=/sbin/ip with_mem_check=no with_plugindir='$(libdir)/openvpn/plugins' with_sysroot=no
```

[server.config](http://pastebin.com/Hen6tJeH)

`chkconfig | grep openvpn`
`openvpn            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off`

Should they all be off if I am not currently running the service?

Couldn't finding anything in dmesg.

Comment: can you `modprobe tun`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something is wrong with the init script because I can start the server fine using this -

`openvpn --mode server --dev tun --tls-server --dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem --ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt  --cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt  --key /etc/openvpn/server.key`

I'll look into it further